# C# UWP Program Stops while read loop with 2666 items list

Tags: c#, list, memory, uwp

I have a list of names (`msfuncionarios`), with name, RFID-MAC (6 pairs of hexadecimal digits) and others.
When I read the RFID (output in 6 decimal digits), I need to check the name with that MAC.

I have the folowing code, but I think that breaks for memory fault.
The list has 2666 items.

I'm running the program on a Raspberry PI 2 v.B.

```
string ConvertUidToName(string uid)
{
    int j, h;
    int k = 0;
    string final="";
    string[] separators = { "-" };

    for (k=0;k <= msfuncionarios.count;k++)
    {
        TextBox_produto.Text = k.ToString();
        string[] words = msfuncionarios[k].MAC.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        i = 0;
        h = 0;

        for (h = 2; h <= 5; h++)
        {
            j = Convert.ToInt32(words[h], 16);
            final = final + j;
        }

        j = 0;

        if (final == uid )
        {
            return msfuncionarios[k].Nome.ToString();
        }

        final = "";
    }

    return uid.ToString();
}
```

Comment: a list can hold way way more than that.. what happens when you debug it

Comment: I think that the problema is not the list, but the 2666 loops the the "for" runs.No?
When i debug the code that funcion does't return nothing.

Comment: If i put the value of k in a textbox in the loop, i only get 0, but without the for loop and replacing k with a number ( employee position) it Works fine

Comment: 2666 loops is not a lot.  the PI may have some smaller restrictions but Id not expect as small as 2666 anythings! (unless they were huge blobs).. Id still expect some form of error.  Are you sure its not just freezing your UI?

Comment: Debbuger don't return any error. I've removed the Split function and COnvert.toint32, and runs fine. Textbox get the 2666 expected value.
Can a charge of tasks be to much for raspberry?

Comment: you didnt have any tasks in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your `for` condition:

```
for (k=0; k <= msfuncionarios.count; k++)
```

You are using the `<=` operator, so the loop runs 2667 times, even for non-existing item `msfuncionarios[2666]` which is out of bounds. You can fix it by using `<` operator.

```
for (k=0; k < msfuncionarios.count; k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I found a bugg in the API that writes in the list. The list contains empty MAC's and the convertion breaks.